# Unit testing a network response. Works when debugging, not when actually running

Tags: android, junit, mockito, android-testing, android-networking

I am currently attempting to test that a network response is actually being received.

***While I understand that this isn't what I should be doing with regards to testing, its a curiosity of my own volition and I'd like to carry on if possible.***

As it stands, I have successfully created the test. A request is sent to a volley queue without issue.

Now the odd part:

That request is never executed. Here's an idea of how I'm testing it:

```
 @Test
    public void testSimpleGetResponseFromServerVolley() throws Exception {
        final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

        NetworkClass.NetworkListener listener = new NetworkClass.NetworkListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) {
                assertThat(response != null);
                System.out.println("Got Response");
                signal.countDown();

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                System.out.println("No Response");
                signal.countDown();
            }
        };
        NetworkClass.getResponseFromServer(null, listener);
        signal.await();
    }
```

This code unexpectedly causes the test to hang and never complete.

**However this is where I stop losing comprehension of the situation:**

If I run the test via *debug* and step through line by line, the test successfully executes, and response is received.

**What I think is happening:**

When I step through via debug, the volley requestQueue successfully carries on and makes the request, and the response is received before `await()` is called.

When I don't step through via debug, `await()` is blocking the thread which handles all of that.

Any ideas on how I can handle this?

Comment: @Test? what is that?

Comment: This is a jUnit test, as my tag suggests.

Comment: If the assert fails, countDown() never gets called.  I don't know how junit behaves in a multithreaded test, but I've seen weird behavior in that situation with other testing frameworks.

Comment: Nope, assert doesn't fail, the test just hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Try using signal.await() with a timeout, then see if the timeout occurs. That way you will know for sure whether it is the reason for test hanging.

Comment: Also it sounds like you may have a thread synchronization issue somewhere. When you run in debug mode, the individual threads will have a smaller chance of clashing with each other because everything is done in a stepwise fashion. When running normally, things happen a lot quicker and there is better chance of issues such as concurrent access etc. Make sure than none of the threads are throwing any exceptions that are not logged.

Comment: @mdewit yes, when the timeout is done the test finishes (without the desired result), so it is the await() that is causing the hang.

Also, I have checked all the threads, there are no exceptions anywhere and the threads all still exist but are all waiting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Volley relies on `Looper.getMainLooper()` to handle its executions. When using a RobolectricTestRunner, Robolectric mocks this out and as such it will not be correctly set up, thus resulting in a failed test.

In my specific case, when I was using breakpoints, the system actually *does* set up the main looper, because the system is utilizing it to show the breakpoints / debugging tools. This thus describes the reasoning behind the behaviour found in my initial question.

Now for a solution as to getting real network responses with Volley during a unit test, the executor must be changed to not be using the main looper.

As an easy solution, create a request queue that relies on `Executor.singleThreadExecutor()` instead of the Main Looper.

Here is what I mean:

```
    //Specific test queue that uses a singleThreadExecutor instead of the mainLooper for testing purposes.
public RequestQueue newVolleyRequestQueueForTest(final Context context) {
    File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "cache/volley");
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
    ResponseDelivery responseDelivery = new ExecutorDelivery(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
    RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir), network, 4, responseDelivery);
    queue.start();
    return queue;
}
```

Then, use that as your request queue for Volley during the tests.

The key here is:

**ResponseDelivery responseDelivery = new ExecutorDelivery(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer a bit so that it's usefull to others as well?

Comment: @middlestump yes sorry, I had forgotten about this answer after I responded to one of the same nature with okhttp. Updating with code now.

Comment: Mockito doesn't like this: new MockContext().getCacheDir() . What could I do about this?

Comment: @AlbertoM you have to mock that function out. I just do this: `when(mockContext.getCacheDir()).thenReturn(new File("test"));`

Comment: I am trying this solution but it doesnt work on my case. I used this function as a Request queue yet I still cannot reach the response in unit tests.