# Testing real network responses with retrofit

Tags: android, junit, retrofit

Before I get the obligatory *"you shouldn't be testing real network responses for XYZ reasons!"*, it should be noted that I am not asking whether or not I should.

I am asking specifically how I would go about doing so, if I wanted to.

After a few hours of struggle I've successfully managed a proper response from *Volley*, and have that test going.

**The problem I'm having now, is that `call.enque(...)` seems to hang on the RobolectricTestRunner.** Unlike Volley, I can't peek in and see whats going on in there [(for Volley, the challenge was not realizing that Looper.getMainLooper doesn't get properly created.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032558/unit-testing-a-network-response-works-when-debugging-not-when-actually-running/37118852#37118852)

So, all I am doing is trying to make a simple request to the server via Retrofit. The issue, as I said, is that the entire system hangs at `call.enqueue`, and there is no error or response ever (even when my await is longer). The network call works fine with volley, but I am getting this snag here with Retrofit. Here's the code if you want to try it. And of course, the function works fine when the app is running.

```
    //in NetworkManager.class
    public void someCall(HashMap properties, NetworkResponseListener listener){
        this.okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(new Cache(appContext, 35 * 1024 * 1024)).build();
        this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(httpPath + apiHost).client(okHttpClient).build();
        this.myService = retrofit.create(MyService.class);

        Call call = myService.someRequest(properties);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        listener.onSuccess(response);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        listener.onError(t);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Service:

```
interface MyService {
    @GET("/api/SomeEndpoint/")
    Call<ResponseBody> someRequest(@QueryMap Map<String, Object> params);
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testSomeCall() throws Exception {
    //Network class has setup OkHttpClient/Service/Retrofit already
    NetworkResponseListener listener = new NetworkResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Response response) {
            this.response = response;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
          //
        }
    };

    NetworkManager.someCall(this.properties, listener);

    await().atMost(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(ResponseReceived());
}
```

Everyone's response on stackoverflow has been 'don't test real network responses', which is really not helpful.

Comment: I don't see what Robolectric has to do with this. retrofit will work with plain java and junit, also are you trying to test what retrofit is doing, or do you want to test your internet connection + the server result? You should explain what you are trying to do in more detail, since it is not very clear

Comment: @davidmedenjak I've updated it. Due to the fact that the network call is done in an asynctask, I can't use basic jUnit. Also, the Volley test is in the same class and absolutely requires the RobolectricTestRunner.

Comment: Why is the network call being done in an AsyncTask? Retrofit is already async.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek the actual construction of the properties map is far more involved and thus is done in an asynctask. The code I've provided is a much less complicated version of the actual methods themselves.

Comment: @davidmedenjak and @GreyBeardedGreek, ignore my comment about Robolectric being a necessity. 

After switching to simply a JUnit4 runner, as well as removing the asynctask, the test hangs at `call.Enqueue()` still. 

Will update question accordingly.

Comment: You should test real BE calls, but not on unit test level :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution is pretty much exactly the same as [for volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032558/unit-testing-a-network-response-works-when-debugging-not-when-actually-running/37118852#37118852).

Retrofit2 will default to the platform callback executor, which will not be correctly instantiated in a test.

Solution is simple. If you wish to test retrofit with real network calls, you must change the callbackExector. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
     .client(okHttpClient).callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
```

Network tests are running successfully.

Comment: Trust me I know. [Here's](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4ik9tf/has_anyone_successfully_tested_real_network/d2z1qnm) my reasoning. 

Was mostly my own curiosity, but then moved to being a little useful check. 

A mock server would not do what I want it to do, because I am testing whether or not the server has changed something that would cause a discrepancy in how Volley/OkHTTP handle things differently, as it has done it the past.

This is only meant to be a sanity check and nothing substantial. The parsing and actual tests are done proper with a mock server. :)